# Why does SEAM throw this error Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction together with hibernate cannot open connection?

Tags: hibernate, jsf, richfaces, seam, jboss6.x

I've ran into this kind of error in my web apps.Here is the scenario.
I have two pages which uses two rich:datatable. This two datatable value points to Seam entity List component lets say SampleList.The component is in Session Scope. The two datatable points to the resultList property of the SampleList component.When i navigate to the second page this error pops up.

Stacktrace:

```
[org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-2) Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: -3f579b7e:e997:4f227422:206 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >;
```

Followed by:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: javax.el.ELException: second.xhtml @119,111 value="#{sampleList.getResultList()}": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:612)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptor.getValue(UIDataAdaptor.java:1624)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.SequenceDataAdaptor.getDataModel(SequenceDataAdaptor.java:65)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.SequenceDataAdaptor.createDataModel(SequenceDataAdaptor.java:59)
    at org.richfaces.component.UIScrollableDataTable.createDataModel(UIScrollableDataTable.java:203)
```

more stack trace

```
at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:146)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:83)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:157)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:83)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:157)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:83)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:157)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:83)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:157)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:83)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:157)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:83)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:157)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:83)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:157)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:83)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:157)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:83)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:157)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:83)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:157)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:83)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:157)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:83)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:157)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:83)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:157)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:83)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:157)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:83)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:157)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:83)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:157)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:83)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:157)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:83)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:157)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxContainerRenderer.encodeAjax(AjaxContainerRenderer.java:123)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.encodeAjax(AjaxViewRoot.java:677)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.encodeChildren(AjaxViewRoot.java:548)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:930)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:592)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:42)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:368)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:495)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

more stack trace

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:614)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:128)
    at org.jboss.seam.framework.EntityQuery.initResultCount(EntityQuery.java:135)
    at org.jboss.seam.framework.EntityQuery.getResultCount(EntityQuery.java:126)
    at com.sample.SampleList.getResultList(SampleList.java:155)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.TransactionInterceptor$1.work(TransactionInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Work.workInTransaction(Work.java:47)
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.SynchronizationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SynchronizationInterceptor.java:32)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:185)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:103)
    at com.sample.SampleList_$$_javassist_seam_92.getResultList(SampleList_$$_javassist_seam_92.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:335)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:280)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstMethodSuffix.getValue(AstMethodSuffix.java:59)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:67)
    at org.jboss.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:71)
    ... 102 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1573)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:696)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:361)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1148)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:88)
    ... 138 more
```

I used `h:outputLink` as navigation link here.
The second page is a complete different view.

I tried to remove the dataTable on the second page and the error is gone.

Can someone tell me what i did wrong here ?

Comment: Include more of the stack trace. Down at the bottom, there will likely be a better explanation for "GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection".

Comment: i will add the stack trace as soon i reproduced the error.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the causes of this error in my case, As i observed it usually happens when a query on my component list takes too long. Reading about transaction and how `SEAM` handle transactions, i ran into transaction timeouts. When a certain query takes too long the `transaction timeout` is reached and the exception is thrown and making the `transaction` not active.

Another cause of this error is when there is a method mark as `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)` 
The explanation is discussed [Here](https://community.jboss.org/thread/187588)

Here is another useful links for Transaction [Timeout](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/understanding-jdbc-internals-and-timeout-configuration/)

Answer (score 1):

I mostly get these "Cannot open connection" exceptions when there is a NullPointException somewhere in my application or when a previous part of the transaction failed.

I get these loop like a4j exceptions when I try to join unjoinable jsf tags. Try removing some tags and build joir page again. You'll probably find a jsf part where jou have a4j:support or some other a4j tag that can not be joined with the other.

```
at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:83)
at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:157)
```

Answer (score 0):

On JBoss AS 5.1 I've changed the

> transaction-jboss-beans.xml file

upgrading the number of secs to

```
<property name="transactionTimeout">10800</property>
```

where 10800 is the transaction time out.